# Setting up Grails and IntelliJ

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I thought I'd give Grails and IntelliJ a look. However, I'm struggling at the first hurdle.
When I go to select the "Groovy SDK" I'm choosing my installation directory - in this case, Grails 2.2.0 - but the OK button on the IDE stays grayed-out. If I choose another of my installation directories - Grails 1.3.7 - the OK button is activated but I get an error message saying my groovy installation is broken.

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

I'm using IntelliJ 12 Community Edition and trying to use Grails 2.2.0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please checkout this [IntelliJ IDEA Features](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/) page, and you will see that some web technologies, like Grails, are only supported in the Ultimate Edition. I would recommend upgrading to the Ultimate Edition, since it has excellent Grails support.

As an alternative, use can use a free IDE which has Grails support: [STS](http://www.springsource.org/sts), [GGTS](http://grails.org/products/ggts).

Comment: That explains it. Looks like I'm sticking with NetBeans for a while then!

Comment: Or back to Eclipse for the majority other half like moi :S

Answer (score 1):

Community Edition doesn't support Grails development.  Note that it is asking for a Groovy SDK (which is supported), not a Grails SDK.